# unexpected ''.$_POST['' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Tags: php

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.$_POST[''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\jawara\fct\proses_penjualan.php on line 6

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
  $kode_produk=$_POST['kode_produk'];
  $jumlah=$_POST['jumlah'];
  $no_nota=$_POST['no_nota'];
  $pembanding=mysql_query ("select stok from produk where kode_produk="'.$_POST['kode_produk'].'"");
  if (mysql_num_rows($pembanding)<$_POST['jumlah']){
      $query=mysql_query("insert into transaksi_keluar_temp values ('','$no_nota','$kode_produk','$jumlah')");
      if($query)
      {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> onload =function(){ alert('Data Berhasil Ditambahkan');}</script>";
      }
      else
      {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> onload =function(){ alert('Stok Kurang Dari $pembanding');}</script>";
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use it as `produk where kode_produk='".$_POST['kode_produk']."'` and `mysql` is deprecated instead use `mysqli or PDO`

Comment: `='"` not `="'`, and `"'"` after rather than `'""`..... but you should be using MySQLi or PDO rather than MySQL in 2016, and prepared statements/bind variables rather than SQL injection holes that you've created.... welcome to the 21st century

Comment: `$pembanding=mysql_query ("select stok from produk where kode_produk='".$kode_produk."'");` try this

Comment: @heri s its your responsibility to check the answers and mark them. This is the way how stack overflow work. you mark answer will help others. Thanks

Comment: thanks for the answer, I want to limit the amount of purchases that do not pass the amount of stock, how do I do it?

Comment: @heris i a the first person who gave you the answer, but you marked another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$pembanding=mysql_query ("select stok from produk where kode_produk="'.$_POST['kode_produk'].'"");
```

To

```
$pembanding=mysql_query ("select stok from produk where kode_produk='$kode_produk'");
```

[**NOTE** : `mysql_*` is deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`]

Comment: thanks for the answer, I want to limit the amount of purchases that do not pass the amount of stock, how do I do it?

Comment: That's different question @heris. I will recommend you to ask new question.

Comment: ok, i will make a new question, thank you so much

Comment: @heris:  If you think this answer of your question helped you. Then, please don't forget to click this answer as correct answer. It will help other user to find it easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your sql query -

Try this -

```
$pembanding=mysql_query (select stok from produk where kode_produk='".$_POST['kode_produk']."');
```

Comment: use `$kode_produk` like @A-2-A suggested

Answer (score 0):

Replace Your Query (In your Query concatenation problem

```
 $pembanding=mysql_query ("select stok from produk where kode_produk="'.$_POST['kode_produk'].'"");
```

> with

```
$pembanding=mysql_query ("select stok from produk where kode_produk="'".$_POST['kode_produk']."'");
```

always try in your best practice do not use $_POST in your query directly

Comment: thanks for the answer,
I want to limit the amount of purchases that do not pass the amount of stock, how do I do it?

Comment: fix your amount  of purcheces and check it before send the stock